# Magento 2.3.1 Store redirect based on GEO IP not working with Cache warmer

Tags: magento2, geoip, store-currency

I am using GEO IP extension to redirect user to specific store. It's working correctly without cache warmer. When i installed cache warmer Store redirect is working correctly but getting incorrect currency.

Please suggest a combination of both third party extension if anybody is using and working correctly.